# onclick event on image element in php does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, events, onclick

Maybe this is a stupid question but i really don't get this.

Small example

```
    <form id="frm1" action="" method="POST">
        <ol>
            <?php

    for ($i=1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {  

    $dirname = "fotos/"."gallery".$i."/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

    foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<li><img name="'."picture".$i.'" src="'.$image.'" onclick="this.form.submit();" /></li>';
    break;
         }

    }
        ?>
        </ol>
    </form>
```

When i submit a form with the onclick event it's not working but as i just put a simple `alert()` in it, then it does work.

Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: can you provide the rest of your code, where is the `<form>` tag

Comment: your form doesn't have any inputs to submit.. what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the form is not proper resolved this way. Just try: `onclick="document.getElementById('frm1').submit();"`

But you can't retrieve the name attr of the img tag this way on the server side. Use a `<input type='hidden'` to store the clicked image for the request, for ex.

Comment: This does not work. :/

Comment: @sorry, i updated my answer.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: @tieboot then mark as accepted?